# Obter o próximo número em angular

Tags: angular, typescript, front-end

Problema é que a função no back-end está funcionando, retorna o número mas no front-end que não estou conseguindo  pegar o número e mostrar na página. É um sequencial vindo do banco de dados.

arquivo **TS**

```
export class NumberSequencial {
    numberseq: number = 0;
}
```

arquivo **Service**

```
numbseq(): Observable<number> {
    return this.http.get<number>(this.url + 'numberseq');
  }
```

É no *Observable* que retorna a resposta? Está correto?

Qualquer sugestão, caminho é bem vindo.

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score -2):

Sim, é no observable que é retornado os dados da api.

Está um pouco genérico os dados que você forneceu, mas a creio que você deva estar atribuindo a chamada, a algum botão. Partindo dessa premissa, você deverá fazer o seguinte.

Injetar o seu serviço no seu componente. Obs: Lembre-se de importar ele nos providers do módulo do seu componente (caso não tenha o providedIn root)

Ex do seu componente

```
export class SeuComponente {
private number: number

constructor(public seuService: Service){}

metodoQuechamaoService() {
  this.seuService.numbseq.subscribe(res => {
    this.number = res
})
}

}
```

Com uma estrutura semelhante a essa, você terá o seu numero, vindo da API e salvo na sua variável number. Com ela você pode fazer o que quiser.

Obs: É importante você se desinscrever depois para evitar o memory leak. Depois pesquise sobre isso. Mas a principio, a resposta pra sua pergunta é essa.